# How to Convert database content language from english to hindi for multilingual android application?

Tags: android, mysql, database, multilingual, mobile-application

I want to create multilingual Android mobile application i have English content database but when i select others language for the same have to shown same content on application like if i select Gujarati then app should be in Gujarati language.

So how can we migrate or convert our database from one language to other language.

is there any database converter tools ? if it is paid no worry for that but content should be perfect after convert.

Comment: You can use google translate API.

Comment: its now working perfect when huge amount of content.....its good for only small sentence ..

Comment: What about 2 databases (one for english and other for Gujarati). And then query the database based on Device's Locale? Other option would be having just different tables for different locales.

Comment: yes that way we can do but the problem is there we must have 2 language database first and i have english language DB  but how can i convert it to others language also ?